# How to load PDF Files faster in Webview?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, pdf

I have a PDF books which is about 1800 (6 MB Size) pages over server .i already use a method to read it in webview successfuly.here is my code.

```
self.webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease];
self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.webView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hilbert1862.com/Books/American Standard Version.pdf"]]];
```

But due to heavy load its takes too much time to display in webview.Can any one share a faster method to display it in webview or display it in parts(means with the scrolling of webview its download new pages).thanx

Answer (score 0):

Part of this project display a PDF (see the FlipReader demo). The project is about doing OpenGL effects as transitions between views.

https://github.com/epatel/EPGLTransitionView

Comment: Thanx @epate but its totally not related about my question.

Comment: @asker Ok, sorry for that. I just thought the rendering of 1800 pages could take some time. The demo renders one page at a time, which I imagine is faster than doing it in the a webview.